# Aligning the bootstrap glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Fiddle** to understand better

**http://jsfiddle.net/fctqp5bt/8/**

I have 3 columns in my website page.

First Column for the Navigation Bar.

Second Column for the arrow glyphicon.

Third Column for the Panel.

But, the glyphicon and panel are not aligned. What is the issue here?

[image]

The code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Subham Soni</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]--> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-header head" id="header">
    <div class="hbg"></div>
    <h1 style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;font-family:'Whiteboard Modern Demo','Arial';"><center>Subham Soni</center></h1>
    <p id="import"><span style="color:rgb(190,0,255);">import</span> java.subhamsoni.*;</p>
    <p id="include"><span style="color:rgb(190,0,255);">#include</span>&nbsp;<span style="color:rgb(255,0,255);">&lt;subhamsoni.h&gt;</span></p>
    <p id="echo"><span style="color:rgb(92,51,23);">echo</span>&nbsp;<span style="color:rgb(255,0,255);">'Subham Soni'</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="maincontent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 menu">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-0 content">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>
                </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">About Me</h3>
            </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                 Panel content
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.head{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
margin-top:10px;
height: 170px;
}

.head .hbg
{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: url('hbg.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
opacity: 0.3;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}

#include
{
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
left: 29%;
top: -38%;
}

#import
{
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
left: 65%;
top: -20%;
display:block;
transform: rotate(-8deg); 
}

#echo
{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
position: relative;
top: -25%;
left: 12%;
}
```

Comment: They look aligned to me... do you mean the glyphicon should be pointing at the panel but it isn't? You just need some `padding` or `margin` sir

Comment: @chriz the arrow should point "About Me"

Comment: Please put your code on JSFiddle.

Comment: @Karmacoma sorry but I am not aware of how to use it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue with your bootstrap columns. You want 12 in total.

I recommend moving the glyphicon inside the md-8 and making it an md-10 so that you have 12 cols in total.

Then just add a css class to your glyphicon and to give it an absolute position to the left of the new md-10 column.

Here's new html code:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right special"></span>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">About Me</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the new css class:

```
.special {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: -5px;
}
```

Comment: Is this solution responsive?

Comment: @xxx Yes, it should be. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

add a margin top to align the icon

```
margin-top:-20px;
```

Comment: Where to add this? In which css?

Comment: you can add it in the css or add it directly in the specific div :) 

<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:-20px;">

Comment: One more doubt please don't mind, is this solution responsive?

Comment: i think but just try to resize your windows manually and you will see if it is responsive or not :)